# Using a USB for Windows installer using Google Drive as image burner

Tags: iso-image, google-drive

I would like to use a USB as bootable device which when booted from a PC connected to a public network, uses Google Drive (and the google credentials in my case) for "burning an image" of windows with a bunch of program installers I have in there. It would be a great tool for me as I could only carry around one USB and connect it to a network device for it to autoinstall not only windows but also de programs included in the remote image. Can this be done somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at [Hirens BootCD PE](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/).

**Don't let the "BootCD" name fool you.**  This tool has been around for a LONG LONG time.  It does indeed get distributed as an ISO but there is a "USB Booting" tab at the top of the page that give simple instructions for booting from USB instead.

The best part (for you) is that you should then be able to tweak it to do whatever you want.

It uses [Windows PE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro?view=windows-11) as it's base and Hiren (whoever that is) added all of the basic stuff to include partitions managers, benchmark tools, file recovery tools, malware bytes, [etc..](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/)

> It does not contain ***any*** pirated software, it contains only free and
> legal software but you can put whatever you want on it after it is
> made.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no. Can a bootable drive be created that **installs** Windows, complete with your selected applications? Yes, [by modifying the WIM file on a Windows ISO](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/ejtdkb/add_preinstall_applications_to_windows_10iso/).

However, can you do this on a random computer in a public place? Certainly not! The installation would require that the PC be yours to modify, licensed for that version of Windows. How would you feel if someone came to your home and took over your computer without permission?

Perhaps you mean you want a portable USB drive from which you can **boot**, not install, an operating system, which already has your applications installed. That's a bit more feasible, with some limitations:

- You'd need permission to go to reboot, selecting the boot device.
- The USB drive would need the drivers for that model PC.

At one time, Microsoft had [Windows to Go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview), made specifically as a portable OS. However, "Windows To Go is removed in Windows 10... It also requires a specific type of USB that is no longer supported."

A more practical portable OS is a Linux distro, such as Ubuntu, with persistent storage, or as [a full installation **on the USB**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330368/live-usb-with-persistence-vs-full-install-on-usb). There are directions at [HowToGeek for persistent storage](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/), [Foss fopr full installation to USB](https://www.fosslinux.com/10212/how-to-install-a-complete-ubuntu-on-a-usb-flash-drive.htm) and elsewhere. However, use of the USB means you *still require permission to reboot the PC* from that drive.